# Double condition in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I am working on a pandas dataframe such as the `df` one produced below:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',3, 2000.0],
                   ['B',4, 4502.5],
                   ['C',5, 6250.0]],
                  columns=['Product', 'Number', 'Value'])
df

    Product     Number  Value
 0    A           3     2000.0
 1    B           4     4502.5
 2    C           5     6250.0
```

I can use an `f-string` in order to add a column, such as:

```
df['Unit_value'] = [f'{x/3}' for x in df["Value"]]
df
```

This runs fine as only 1 variable `x` is involved: the denominator of `x/3` is constant.
Can I do something equivalent (using `f-string`), but with a variable `y` in denominator, `y` being the `Number` corresponding to the given `Value`?
What I would like to have is:

```
    Product     Number  Value   Unit_Value
0      A          3     2000.0  666.66
1      B          4     4502.5  1125.63
2      C          5     6250.0  1250.00
```

Where: `666.66=2000.0/3 , 1125.63=4502.5/4 , 1250.00=/5`

I thought of something like `for x in df["Value"] and y in df["Number"]` and tried to play with that, but this kind of syntax doesn't work...

Comment: Why are you using f-strings for this when you could just use an expression? You know an f-string outputs a string, not a float, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.itertuples()`.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',3, 2000.0],
                   ['B',4, 4502.5],
                   ['C',5, 6250.0]],
                  columns=['Product', 'Number', 'Value'])
df['Unit_value'] = [tup.Value / tup.Number for tup in df.itertuples()]

print(df)
```

You could also use a pure python approach with `zip`.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',3, 2000.0],
                   ['B',4, 4502.5],
                   ['C',5, 6250.0]],
                  columns=['Product', 'Number', 'Value'])
df['Unit_value'] = [val / num for num, val in zip(df['Number'], df['Value'])]

print(df)
```

`zip` returns an iterable of `tuple`s that you can then unpack into variables.

If you really want to you could do it with f strings but that would return a string and remove the ability (or at least make it more difficult) to do further calculations.

Comment: Very nice. Much better than my way. Wanting to use `f-string` was an attempt to use this command in a slightly more complicated context than usual, just to practice with `f-string`, which I am not familiar with; but it is true that it is not necessary ...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use f-strings for this, since they output strings instead of floats. Instead, just use the plain expressions.

I'm not too familiar with Pandas, but I believe the best way to do this is by treating the columns like arrays, i.e. do the operation on the two columns themselves:

```
>>> df['Unit_value'] = df["Value"] / df["Number"]
>>> df
  Product  Number   Value   Unit_value
0       A       3  2000.0   666.666667
1       B       4  4502.5  1125.625000
2       C       5  6250.0  1250.000000
```

Otherwise, for a vanilla Python way to do it, use `zip`. See  [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807/4518341)

```
>>> df['Unit_value'] = [x/y for x, y in zip(df["Value"], df["Number"])]
>>> df
  Product  Number   Value   Unit_value
0       A       3  2000.0   666.666667
1       B       4  4502.5  1125.625000
2       C       5  6250.0  1250.000000
```